# Does the matrix product $X^T X$ have a special meaning?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics

I have come across this specific matrix product several times, lately in the context of stochastic linear models where it is an integral part of the Least Squares Estimator (LSE). Often times in linear algebra there is some beautiful intuition hidden behind recurring formulae and since I don't see the one behind this one I'm asking for help.

Is there a geometric interpretation or special meaning for the matrix product

$$X^T X$$

for a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ with $p \leq n$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix

Comment: It's a generalization of the dot product which is the case when $p=1$.

Comment: It sends a vector $a_0$ to the gradient of $\frac{1}{2} \| X a \|^2$ at $a=a_0$. That is one way to understand its significance in the context of least squares. There is another way to think of how it arises by thinking about projection: the projection of $b$ onto the range of $X$, call it $x^*$, will have the property that $b-x^*$ is orthogonal to $X a$ for all $a$. Writing out the dot product of $b-x^*$ with $Xa$ and replacing $x^*=Xp$ reveals the appearance of $X^T X$.

Comment: This is neither a geometric interpretation nor special meaning, but if $X$ is not square, $X^\top X$ will be.

Comment: [Stiefel manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold)

Comment: There are some statistical interpretation about that. You may start with the case that columns of $X$ are orthogonal.

Comment: Gilbert Strang emphasizes the recurring pattern $A^T A$ and $A^T C A$ (with $C$ symmetric positive definite) in his linear algebra and applied math books. "I have learned to look for $A^T CA$." A great example is that $-\text{div}$ is the adjoint of $\nabla$, so the (negative) Laplacian fits the pattern $A^T A$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have an inner product space, but what you care about is not the dot product of the two vectors, but the dot product of their images under $X.$ Well,

$$\langle X a, X b\rangle = a^t X^t X b.$$

Note that the correct way to think of $X^t X$ is as a quadratic form, not so much a linear transformation.

Answer (score 2):

When we find the least squares solution $\hat{x}$ to a system $Ax = b$, we are finding the point $p = A\hat{x}$ of the column space that is closest to $b$. Geometrically, this is given by projecting $b$ onto the column space of $A$. The error $e = b - p$ is thus orthogonal to the column space. The orthogonal complement of the column space of $A$ is the nullspace of $A^T$, so this means we want $A^Te = 0$. But $e = b - p = b - A\hat{x}$, so $A^Te = 0$ is equivalent to $A^T(b - A\hat{x}) = 0$, or $A^TA\hat{x} = A^Tb$. This gives us the normal equations, with the appearance of the matrix $A^TA$.